# retrieve JSON array and put it into an Array in java?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

im retrieving the Array of JSON data and trying to diplay and access it.But when i tried to display it it only displays the last row from the array of JSON data.And when i tried to do something like json1.get(2)(json1 here is JSONArray containing JSONObject) i get array out of bound error.
Please tell me what im doing wrong and how can i retrive the JSON 
Below is the relevant code to this question.

Thank You.

im calling getAllFreebies function of UserFunctions.java class from Freebies.java class

```
UserFunctions uf = new UserFunctions();
JSONObject json = uf.getAllFreebies();
```

Below is the code of my getAllFreebies() function from UserFunctions.java class:

```
public JSONObject getAllFreebies(){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", getAllFreebies_tag));
    JSONObject json  = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getAllFreebiesURL,params);
    JSONArray json1 = new JSONArray();
    json1.put(json);
    try {
        System.out.println(json1.get(2));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Below is the code from index.php class where im calling getFreebies() function of DB_Functions.php class

```
else if($tag = 'getAllFreebies'){
                $username = "";
                $catagory = "";
                $subcatagory = "";
                $title = "";
                $condition = "";
                $description = "";
                $address = "";
                $city = "";
                $state = "";
                $country = "";
                $zipcode = "";
                $posted_on= "";
                    $getAllFreebies = $db->getFreebies($username,$catagory,$subcatagory,$title,$condition,$description,$address,$city,$state,$country,$zipcode,$posted_on);
            $data = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAllFreebies)) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $data[] = array(
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["username"] = $row["username"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["catagory"] = $row["catagory"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["subcatagory"] = $row["subcatagory"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["title"] = $row["title"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["item_condition"] = $row["item_condition"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["description"] = $row["description"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["address"] = $row["address"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["city"] =  $row["city"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["state"] = $row["state"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["country"] = $row["country"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["zipcode"] = $row["zipcode"],
            $response["getAllFreebies"]["posted_on"] = $row["posted_on"]);}
            echo json_encode($response);
                    }// end of getAllFreebies tag
```

Below is the code of getFreebies() function of DB_Functions.php

```
public function getFreebies(){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freebie") or die(mysql_error());
return($result);
}
```

UPDATE:I added the following in my JSONParser class in order to parse JSONArray
    public JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url, List params) {

```
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        jarray.put(jObj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jarray;

}
```

And I changed getAllFreebie() to retrieve JSONArray

```
public JSONArray getAllFreebies() {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", getAllFreebies_tag));
    JSONArray json = jsonParser.getJSONArrayFromUrl(getAllFreebiesURL,
            params);
    return json;
}
```

Still im only getting single row instead of all the rows.Can anyone pls tell me what am i doing wrong.Thanks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Update your code to this:</strike>

```
// Initialize the array with your JSON string.
JSONArray json1 = new JSONArray(json);

// This line adds your String as the first element to
// the JSON array and is incorrect. You can safely remove it.
//json1.put(json);
```

**EDIT:** Try this updated version of the code you posted:

```
// Making HTTP request
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    try {
        // Get our response as a String.
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON: "+jsonString);

        // Parse the JSON String into a JSONArray object.
        return new JSONArray(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

Comment: thanks for the response.i tried to do this and it eclipse gives me an error "The constructor JSONArray(JSONObject) is undefined" Also can you pls take a look at my index.php code and check whether everything is correct? im getting 1 row so i might not be getting others rows

Comment: Sorry, I read your example wrong. The problem is in the `jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl` method. What does that method code look like? Is that something you wrote or a library you're using? The code sample I posted would work just fine if your `json` variable was a String containing a JSON array.

Comment: thanks for the reply.that function just go to the URL and retrieve JSON.But im not sure whether im returning JSON array containing multiple rows of data or just 1 row of data :S

Comment: actually you are right jsonParser is wrong.It only parses Objects.Lemme try to write parser for JSONArray and see if it works.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a tweaked version of the code you just posted. Please give it a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: it says  httpResponse cannot be resolved at line    String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

Comment: thanks for the reply.i tried out the code.Its still retrieving last row of the data and gave an error that "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value: (here it prints out JSON row thats retrieved) of type json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray   " :(

Comment: Can you post what the raw jsonString value looks like? The Log statement in my example should send it to your logcat.

Comment: thanks for the reply.actually the code that you provided is working just fine.The problem was that i was doing return json_encode($response) instead of json_encode($data) in my index.php that's why it was returning only one row instead of an 1.array duh me :)

Comment: Hah! Good catch, I honestly didn't look over your PHP very closely.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code:

```
JSONObject json  = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(getAllFreebiesURL,params);
JSONArray json1 = new JSONArray();
json1.put(json);
try {
    System.out.println(json1.get(2));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You create a new *empty* `JSONArray`, add one element to it, and then attempt to access its second element.

Is `getJSONFromUrl` supposed to parse an object or an array? I believe you need it to return a `JSONArray` instead.

Comment: so my function to retrieve JSON array would like something like public JSONObject[] getAllFreebies(){} ?!

Comment: @Viking: I would actually do `JSONArray getAllFreebies()`, don't you expect an array of _JSON_ freebies?

Comment: i need too write a custom getJSONArrayFromURL method in my JSONParser class.getJSONFromUrl is just getting JSONObject and not JSONArray.